# How to configure JavaFX "Exception in Application Start Method"?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am using JavaFX with Eclipse as the IDE. Everytime there is an exception, `System.err` will print `Exception in Application Start Method`. Only when I enter the debug perspective and press "Step Return" a few times would the stack trace be printed. How do I configure it such that the stack trace will be printed automatically when there is an Exception?

Comment: The debugger needs to reach the point where a) the exception is handled or b) the topmost frame of the stack does not handle the exception and the uncaughtexceptionhandler does something with that exception. The debugger simply does not know what to do with that exception, until it reaches one of those points. If you use your own try - catch though, you could add a breakpoint in the catch clause and simply use "run" to get to that breakpoint...